# Allow users to select any option on Google Home device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing an AoG / Google Assistant app which will provide feature to list some items and user can select any one item to know more about it.

I am using [List](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list) to show the items and an intent with **actions_intent_OPTION** will listen for user input. It is working fine for mobile and screen devices. Now I want to do same thing on Google Home ( Speaker only) device.

Is it possible to provide option selection feature on Google Home. One thing I would like to add here is that, "I can not use entities to get inputs because we are creating items dynamically."

Answer (score 1):

A List object will not work on audio-only devices, as there is no screen. As such, you will probably want to use either `@sys.any` to capture a parameter on audio devices, or use [session entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-session) to define the types of parameters that you'd want to capture.